# Map json to object with retrofit (GSON)

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

Json I get from Server is :

```
 {
"data" :   [
      { "id":1, "url": "http://example.com/image1"   },
      { "id":2, "url": "http://example.com/image2"   },
      { "id":3, "url": "http://example.com/image3"   }
  ]
}
```

and the class I have for mapping is

```
public class Repository {
    private List<Event> events;
}
```

although I get a success from retrofit I can't map it to my object.
Also I have class `Event` with int id and String url.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

change it like this

```
public class Repository {
    private List<Event> data;
}
```

or

```
public class Repository {
    @SerializedName("data")
    private List<Event> events;
}
```